# The type must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet<TEntity>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

estou tentando configurar um enum no ENTITY FRAMEWORK. Porém não estou tendo sucesso.

Meu Context está assim:

```
public class MoradaWebContext : DbContext
{
 public DbSet<MeuEnum> Status { get; set; }
}
```

O Enum está assim:

```
public enum MeuEnum
{
        Aberta = 1,
        Fechada = 4,
        Aguardando = 5,
}
```

E eu queria deixar configurado no mapeamento corretamente. Inclusive no Banco. (Eu tenho q ver inclusive como vou cadastrá-lo no Banco)

Porém está retornando este erro:

> The type must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet'

Usei como referência este link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh859576(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Acredito que você não possa fazer um DbSet do tipo de um Enum ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível.

Você precisa passar uma classe para `DbSet`.

Um enum pode ser uma propriedade de um model, mas nunca um model propriamente dito. Ou seja, isso é aceitável

```
public MeuModel 
{
    public MeuEnum Status { get; set; }
}
```

Mas isto que você está tentando fazer não é válido.

Comment: O Enum pode ser usado como atributo em alguma classe sua, mas passado como tipo para o DbSet é impossível

Comment: Deixo esse artigo escrito pelo incrível Claudenir Andrade sobre [Entendendo Valores e Referências no C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc517979.aspx) para enriquecer ainda mais essa resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma classe, que receba o enum e essa classe estar relacionada com a outra que você precisa.

Em outras palavras, vai ser uma classe onde sua chave primária será o enum.

*Utilizo o seguinte código:*

1. Uma classe Genérica, que recebe o tipo do `enum`:

   ```
   public class EnumTable<TEnum>
       where TEnum : struct
   {
       public TEnum Id { get; set; }
       public string Nome { get; set; }
       public string Descricao { get; set; }

       protected EnumTable() { }

       public EnumTable(TEnum enumType)
       {
           if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
           {
               throw new Exception($"Argumento inválido do tipo {typeof(TEnum)}");
           }

           Id = enumType;
           Nome = enumType.ToString();
           Descricao = enumType.GetEnumDescription<TEnum>();
       }

       public static implicit operator EnumTable<TEnum>(TEnum enumType) => new EnumTable<TEnum>(enumType);
       public static implicit operator TEnum(EnumTable<TEnum> status) => status.Id;
   }
   ```
2. Dois métodos de extensão, para pegar a descrição e fazer o seed:

   ```
         public static string GetEnumDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum item)
   => item.GetType()
          .GetField(item.ToString())
          .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
          .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
          .FirstOrDefault()?.Description ?? string.Empty;



     public static void SeedEnumValues<T, TEnum>(this IDbSet<T> dbSet, Func<TEnum, T> converter)
   where T : class
     {
             Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
               .Cast<object>()
               .Select(value => converter((TEnum)value))
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(instance => dbSet.AddOrUpdate(instance));
     }
   ```
3. Seu `enum`:

   ```
   public enum MeuEnum
   {
      [Description("Em Aberto")]
       Aberta = 1,

      [Description("Fechado")]
       Fechada = 4,

      [Description("Aguardando alguma coisa")]
       Aguardando = 5
   }
   ```
4. A sua classe, herdando a classe genérica, informando seu enum:

   ```
   public class MeuEnumClass: EnumTable<MeuEnum>
   {
       public MeuEnumClass(MeuEnum enumType) : base(enumType)
       {

       }

       public MeuEnumClass() : base() { } //deve ser definido o construtor padrão para o EF
   }
   ```
5. Seu DbSet:

   ```
   public DbSet<MeuEnumClass> Status { get; set; }
   ```
6. Sobrescreva o método Seed da classe de configuração do EF:

   ```
   protected override void Seed(SeuDbContext context)
   {
       context.Status.SeedEnumValues<MeuEnumClass, MeuEnum>(@enum => new MeuEnumClass(@enum));
   }
   ```
7. Pronto. Crie a `migration` e atualize o bando de dados.

**Será criada a tabela com os campos Id, Nome e Descrição onde:**

- Id: É a PK e também o `enum` propriamente dito. (No banco é informado um inteiro)
- Nome: É o Valor do `enum`, por exemplo "Aberta" no código atual
- Descrição É o valor do atributo `Description` informado no `enum`, por exemplo "Em Aberto" no código atual.

> Código retirado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44166999/4713574

Me atendeu perfeitamente, estou colocando como resposta caso alguém venha a precisar de algo assim.