# Como utilizar enum com EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, enums

Tenho um relacionamento do meu sistema onde uma classe faz relacionamento com outra, **porém essa outra classe não há em lugar nenhum do sistema para alterar/deletar seu estado** (são apenas dados estáticos).

Gostaria de saber se o ideal a isso seria usar **enum** e como eu **utilizo enums no C# usando EntityFramework?**

O enum tem a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de fazer isso ser refletido no banco em forma de tabela e já preenchido (Já que o usuário não irá poder modificar nada desta tabela)

Comment: Represente isso em um model comum e uma tabela na sua base de dados ...! acho melhor

Comment: Como Linq respondeu, não é possível representar enum diretamente no banco, você precisa de uma classe. Mas entendo sua necessidade e tive uma semelhante. Esta solução resolveu pra mim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558339/4713574 . Espero que ajude. Caso necessário, a noite vejo o código da forma que utilizei e compartilho

Comment: Ok @RovannLinhalis, muito obrigado pela atenção, estou no aguardo!

Comment: @RenanNarciso coloquei como resposta na pergunta que gerou duplicidade. Espero que ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277972/69359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível. No Entity Framework tipos por valor não podem representar uma tabela.

Comment: Bom, vendo o tópico que você fez referência, então é entendido que um Enum não pode ser refletido no banco e virar uma tabela, porém consigo usar meu enum em um Model, correto?

Comment: @RenanNarciso Isso

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558339/4713574

Comment: Continua não sendo possível.